# FreeBSD 10.3 и выход в Инет для отдельной локальной машины (настройка IPFW)

Tags: сеть, freebsd, nat, ipfw

Коллеги, здравствуйте. 
Задачу выпустить только определённые компьютеры в сеть. 
Пересобрал ядро с параметрами:

```
options         IPFIREWALL 
options         IPFIREWALL_VERBOSE 
options         IPFIREWALL_VERBOSE_LIMIT=220 
options         IPDIVERT 
options         IPFIREWALL_DEFAULT_TO_ACCEPT 
options         DUMMYNET 
options         IPFIREWALL_NAT 
options         LIBALIAS 
options         MROUTING 

ifconfig 
em0:    inet 10.2.54.189 смотрит в сторону провайдера 
em1:    inet 192.168.168.199 смотрит в сторону локалки
```

в /etc/rc.conf прописал:

```
gateway_enable="YES" 
hostname="svin" 
firewall_nat_enable="YES" 
natd_enable="YES" 
natd_flags="" 
sshd_enable="YES" 
firewall_enable="YES" 
firewall_type="open" 
inetd_enable="YES" 
clear_tmp_enable="YES" 
keymap="us.iso" 
linux_enable="YES" 
imspector_enable="YES"
```

в /etc/rc.local закинул

```
/sbin/natd -f /etc/natd.conf -a 10.2.54.189 -p 8668 
/sbin/ipfw add 50 divert 8668 ip4 from 192.168.168.198 to any via em0
```

Пытаюсь с 192.168.168.198 пингануть 8.8.8.8 - ничего не получаю. 
Фиксирую на em1 ICMP от 192.168.168.198, так же на em0 фисирую запросы и ответы от 10.2.54.189 на 8.8.8.8

Если прописываю: ipfw add 50 divert 8668 ip4 from any to any via em0 
То всё пингуется. В чём я напортачил? Мне не нужно всех выпускать, а только определённых.

примечание:
точно такая же конфигурация на FreeBSD 8. отлично отрабатывает и выпускает в сеть определенный комп, но требуется именно FreeBSD 10.3.
Непонятно, почему то что работало на 8-ке не работает на 10, пробовал на чистой FreeBSD 8 настроить - все сработало. А на 10й работает только any to any а только один пк выпустить не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так (работает в FreeBSD 10.1):

1. В `/etc/rc.conf` пропиши:

   ```
   gateway_enable="YES"
   firewall_enable="YES"
   firewall_nat_interface="tun0"
   firewall_nat_enable="YES"
   firewall_type="OPEN"
   firewall_script="/etc/rules.ipfw"
   ```
2. В конфиге файрвола (`/etc/rules.ipfw`) укажи:

   ```
   ipfw nat 1 config if em0 log reset same_ports
   ipfw add nat 1 ip from 192.168.168.198 to any out via em0
   ipfw add nat 1 ip from any to me in via em0
   ```

В итоге должен получиться SourceNat только для одного ip 192.168.168.198.